# Match anything until first occurrence of word with regex

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have the following sentence:

```
I'm screaming to my friend hello, hello, hello!
```

I want to match anything between the leading `I'm` and the first occurrence of the word `hello`.

I have the following regular expression:

```
I'm[^hello]*
```

This is working very well if I had a single character instead of a whole word, in my case `hello`.

It seams like `hello` isn't recognized as a whole word but as single characters with an `OR` operator between them.

The result I get is: `I'm scr`

The expected result is: `I'm screaming to my friend`

How can I match anything until the first occurrence of the word `hello`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```regex
I'm (?:(?!\bhello\b).)*
```

If your regex tool/language support capture groups, then use them instead:

```regex
(I'm .*?)(?:\bhello\b|$)
```